# ASP: Either EOF or BOF is True, but I have records and they are displaying

Tags: mysql, vbscript, asp-classic, repeat

I have a database with around 40 records, I am trying to display them in a table fashion with 3 columns but extends to the extent of the records.

All of the records display but when it gets to the very end of the record list i get what looks like another cell with the message:

> ADODB.Field error '800a0bcd' Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current
>   record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current
>   record. /products/index1.asp, line 668

in, I'll post the code below, can anyone help, I've searched the web but can't find anything. This is the only way that I could find to display the records in a 3 wide table, if there is a better way, even using CSS, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
<table border="0">
<tr><td class="product_title">Our Products</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="5" height="7"></td></tr>
  <% While ((Repeat1__numRows <> 3) AND (NOT products_page.EOF)) %>
    <tr>

      <td align="center" valign="middle">
          <div class="thumbgrey" align="center">
              <a href="/products/<%=(products_page.Fields.Item("" & lang & "_URL").Value)%>" title="<%=(products_page.Fields.Item("" & lang & "_title").Value)%>">
                <img src="/images/product_page/<%=(products_page.Fields.Item("" & lang & "_image").Value)%>" alt="<%=(products_page.Fields.Item("" & lang & "_title").Value)%>" width="230" height="97" border="0" />
              </a>
          </div>
      </td>
      <% 
  Repeat1__index=Repeat1__index+1
  Repeat1__numRows=Repeat1__numRows-1
  products_page.MoveNext()

%>

<td align="center" valign="middle">
          <div class="thumbgrey" align="center">
              <a href="/products/<%=(products_page.Fields.Item("" & lang & "_URL").Value)%>" title="<%=(products_page.Fields.Item("" & lang & "_title").Value)%>">
                <img src="/images/product_page/<%=(products_page.Fields.Item("" & lang & "_image").Value)%>" alt="<%=(products_page.Fields.Item("" & lang & "_title").Value)%>" width="230" height="97" border="0" />
              </a>
          </div>
      </td>
      <% 
  Repeat1__index=Repeat1__index+1
  Repeat1__numRows=Repeat1__numRows-1
  products_page.MoveNext()

%>

<td align="center" valign="middle">
          <div class="thumbgrey" align="center">
              <a href="/products/<%=(products_page.Fields.Item("" & lang & "_URL").Value)%>" title="<%=(products_page.Fields.Item("" & lang & "_title").Value)%>">
                <img src="/images/product_page/<%=(products_page.Fields.Item("" & lang & "_image").Value)%>" alt="<%=(products_page.Fields.Item("" & lang & "_title").Value)%>" width="230" height="97" border="0" />
              </a>
          </div>
      </td>
      <% 
  Repeat1__index=Repeat1__index+1
  Repeat1__numRows=Repeat1__numRows-1
  products_page.MoveNext()
  Wend
%>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you should just add this into a loop which creates a new row after every third entry, this way your not re-writing the same code 3 times and will save work when updating the code.

```
<table border="0">
    <tr><td class="product_title">Our Products</td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="3" height="7"></td></tr>
    <tr>
        <% 
        Repeat1__index = 1
        Do While (NOT products_page.EOF) 
            %>
            <td align="center" valign="middle">
                <div class="thumbgrey" align="center">
                    <a href="/products/<%=(products_page.Fields.Item("" & lang & "_URL").Value)%>" title="<%=(products_page.Fields.Item("" & lang & "_title").Value)%>">
                        <img src="/images/product_page/<%=(products_page.Fields.Item("" & lang & "_image").Value)%>" alt="<%=(products_page.Fields.Item("" & lang & "_title").Value)%>" width="230" height="97" border="0" />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </td>
            <% 
            Repeat1__index = Repeat1__index+1
            If Repeat1__index = 4 Then
                Response.Write("</tr><tr>")
                Repeat1__index = 1
            End If
            products_page.MoveNext()
        Loop
        If Repeat1__index > 1 Then 
            Response.Write("<td colspan='" & 4-Repeat1__index & "'></td>")
        End If
        %>
    </tr>

</table>
```

The last if statement (*If Repeat1__index > 1 Then*) will tidy up the remaining columns if needed so if there is 4 entries being returned it will create 1 full row of three and the last row will only have 1 entry so adds the last table cell to even out the row.

nb. Don't forget to close products_page and set it to Nothing at the end

```
products_page.Close()
Set products_page = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your recordset does not contain a multiple of 3 rows.

You get the error while trying to write the second or third column.

Try like this (I omitted the actual writing of the images because it's not relevant):

```
<%While Not products_page.EOF%>

    <tr>

        <td>
            <%' first image%>
            <div class="thumbgrey" align="center">...</div>
            <%products_page.MoveNext()%>
        </td>

        <td>

            <%If Not products_page.EOF Then%>
                <%' second image%>
                <div class="thumbgrey" align="center">...</div>
                <%products_page.MoveNext()%>
            <%Else%>
                &nbsp;
            <%End If%>

        </td>

        <td>

            <%If Not products_page.EOF Then%>
                <%' third image%>
                <div class="thumbgrey" align="center">...</div>
                <%products_page.MoveNext()%>
            <%Else%>
                &nbsp;
            <%End If%>

       </td>

   </tr>

<%Wend%>
```

Comment: I realise Jan your just reformatting the OPs code to make it work. But @07lodgeT please consider using `If Not products_page.EOF Then Set data = products_page.GetRows()` that way you can close off the memory hungry `ADODB.Recordset` and use an 2 dimensional `Array` to iterate through your data as you see fit `GetRows()` returns a 2 dimensional array of columns, rows so second column in the first row would be `data(1, 0)` (all ordinals in arrays start from 0).

Comment: @07lodgeT Also using an array means using `Mod()` to handle the number of `<td>`s per `<tr>` would be a doddle! `Mod()` is great for this type of thing specify the the number of columns per row and watch [the magic happen](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/article.php/c19315/The-Magical-Mod-Function.htm). All that duplication of code and mark-up is unnecessary.

Comment: Only deal breaker I can see is the use of `products_page.Fields.Item("" & lang & "_URL").Value` as this requires access to `Field` metadata which the `Array` will not contain.